# background image is not coming above the text while printing

Tags: html, css

I want background image to come above all the text.
below is my code

```html
<style>

            body {
                background-image: url('http://test.sixorbit.com/rpkfiles/cancelled.png')!important;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;

                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
                position: relative!important;
                z-index: 500!important;


            }

</style>
```

How can i show all the background image above the text instead of behind.

Comment: `z-index` can't move parent under children. Use any additional element with the red text and position it absolutely above the other content.

Comment: the image ''cancelled.png' cannot be a background image of body element. You must put it into a tag <img> and set it with z-index.

Answer (score 0):

try `:before` or `:after` pseudo

```
    body:before{
content:"";
width:100vw;
height:100vw;
z-index:500;
background-image:url(image path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to comment under your question I've prepared a working demo how to do it with additional element. It can be `body:after` pseudoelement too.

No `z-index`, `!important`s, etc. needed.

```css
table {width: 100%; background: green;}

#overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-image: url('http://test.sixorbit.com/rpkfiles/cancelled.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: z-index is not mandatory but it can be if for some reason he is using positionning with other elements in the page

Comment: @TemaniAfif: z-index on `body` is nonsense at all. The reason I've mentioned in the comment under question, parents can't be moved under their children using z-index. `500! important` is just a despiration, `z-index` in hundreds isn't good to use. If z-index is needed, the _normal_ values should be used.

Comment: no z-index on the body :) i agree with this but maybe he's using z-index with another element inside the body (since we don't know all his content). maybe he fixed an element and give it a z-index so it can be below your overlay ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: sure, it's possible. We don't know all styles, from the code snippet z-index isn't necessary :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using a `.wrapper` instead of the body. That way you can place the image relative to the invoice size

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptg86u6d/)

```css
.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://test.sixorbit.com/rpkfiles/cancelled.png') no-repeat bottom right /contain;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
}

.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.xininventory.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/sample-tax-invoice.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```